# A simple example showing that $r(a+b) \neq r(a) + r(b)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, radicals

I was given an example to take the ideal of the irreducible polynomial $(x^2 + p),$ where $p$ is a prime and the ideal $(p)$ to show that the radical of the sum of ideals is not equal to the sum of the radicals.

But I do not quite understand the role of $x$ here and how it shows that the radical of the sum of ideals is not equal to the sum of the radicals. I also found this question here on the site [Radical ideals in $\mathbb Z[x]$ such that their sum is not radical](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1701240/radical-ideals-in-mathbb-zx-such-that-their-sum-is-not-radical) but still I do not understand.

Comment: In which ring are you working?

Comment: $\mathbb Z[X]$ @linkja

Answer (score 2):

We work in the ring $\mathbb{Z}[X]$. Any irreducible polynomial generates a prime ideal, which is thus a radical ideal. In particular, if $p$ is a prime number, then $I := \langle X^2 + p \rangle$ and $J := \langle p \rangle$ are radical ideals in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$. Their sum is $I+J=\langle X^2 + p , p \rangle = \langle X^2 , p \rangle$. This is not a radical ideal, since $X^2 \in \langle X^2 , p \rangle$ but (you have to prove this) $X \notin \langle X^2 , p \rangle$. So in this case, $r(I)+r(J)$ is strictly contained in $r(I+J)$: this is the inclusion $\langle X^2 , p \rangle \subset \langle X , p \rangle$.

Comment: I do not think your explanation is following the same terminology I am using and so I do not understand you and I do not see an answer to my question in your answer

Comment: I have edited the answer accordingly. I was assuming that you only want to find *some* example.